# ASP.NET / Cookies

Tags: asp.net

Please imagine this scenario:

1. User visits the site for the first time and we set a cookie.
2. The user visits the site a long time later (long enough to be using a new session)

Is that cookie available to read on the very first page_load of the new visit?

The behavour i'm seeing is that it isn't. Only if I refresh or browse to another page on the site. I'm not sure if that is an issue with my code, or by design.

Thanks

Comment: We'd need to see the *minimum* code you can use to reproduce the issue to be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *appropriately* set the [Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.expires%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `HttpCookie`:

```
  aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
```

The [Cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) expiration date instructs the browser on how long to retain the cookie.  Once the expiration date has past, the cookie will no longer be sent with each browser request.

If the cookie is created correctly, then it will be sent on every subsequent requests to the same domain (or child domain).  This will translate to you being able to read the cookie during a subsequent `page_load` event.